# Vim segfaults randomly when autcompleting a word with ctrl-n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, vim, crash, segmentation-fault

I'm using the system vim (7.2) that comes with mac osx (currently 10.6.7). I'm doing rails development mainly with rails.vim.

Randomly, when I try to autocomplet a word using ctrl-n vim will segfault and exit. Any ideas what is causing this? Or any ideas on how I can start looking into what is causing this? I'm not able to get it to crash reliably but it's fairly often.

Here's a short clip of what shows in mac's console app

```
Process:         vim [34386]
Path:            /usr/bin/vim
Identifier:      vim
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  zsh [34284]

Date/Time:       2011-08-28 15:22:56.168 +0800
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.7 (10J869)
Report Version:  6

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x0000000100500000
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Application Specific Information:
*** error for object 0x1004fa928: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.


Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff832af5d6 __kill + 10
1   vim                             0x0000000100119eb3 0x100000000 + 1154739
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff832c166a _sigtramp + 26
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff832af5d6 __kill + 10
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8334fcd6 abort + 83
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8333e90d szone_error + 519
6   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff83265d2b tiny_malloc_from_free_list + 144
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff83264fdd szone_malloc_should_clear + 242
8   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff83264eaa malloc_zone_malloc + 82
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff832631a8 malloc + 44
10  vim                             0x0000000100099826 0x100000000 + 628774
```

Comment: I guess you first need to update. You can spend much time finding out where bug is located... and then realize that it is fixed in latest vim.

Comment: @ZyX thanks for the suggestion. I also got the same error with vim 7.3.266? The bug seems to be related to when I have existing swap files.

Comment: @Brand: can you elaborate on that? Perhaps posting your own question and linking it? Alternatively, you could set a bounty

Comment: Same here - consistently get segfault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time to

1. collect system information

   - `ldd $(which vim)`
   - `uname -a`
2. get a coredump (on linux, you might need to do `ulimit -c unlimited`)
3. aternatively, run vim in the debugger

.

```
  gdb $(which vim)
  (gdb) break main
  (gdb) run file1.txt
  (gdb) break abort
  (gdb) break assert
```

(think of other things to monitor)

When receiving a breakpoint/signal:

```
  (gdb) bt
  (gdb) info threads
  (gdb) thread apply all bt

  (gdb) bt full
  (gdb) thread apply all bt full
```

Send relevant output to the vim bugs list (do `:he bugs` in vim for detailed steps).

> **Of course, the output of the stack traces will greatly improve once you install the debug symbols with the packages for vim (and it's dependencies). I don't know how to do that on Macs, sry**

Comment: It is good answer, but nobody needs backtrace for an old version of vim.

Comment: @ZyX: thank you; Note how ubuntu lucid (**LTS**) still comes with 7.2; Also I don't expect this to be a pure vim bug - and as such don't anticipate it being fixed in the meantime. I'm thinking ABI/library conflict. Ctrl-N style completion is _old_ and should be really well-tested by now

Comment: this is not really an answer, is it? I have the same problem as Brand, and I'm completely at a loss... especially since I can go for weeks without Vim crashing

Comment: @iain I just found this thread: http://code.google.com/p/macvim/issues/detail?id=370 which suggest you can install the 32bit version from brew. This suppposedly well worked for others